# Where can I find the source for "python mode" when editing emacs configuration for mac os x?

Tags: python, macos, emacs

I'm looking to play with python mode for emacs on mac os x, but I can't seem to find the source files for the mode.

What are the standard locations, where a default installation of emacs might have put its modes when installed on Mac OS X?

(I'm using GNU Emacs 24.0.95.1 (i386-apple-darwin11.3.0, NS apple-appkit-1138.32))

Comment: Since GNU Emacs 24 isn't actually out yet, you're clearly using either a custom build—in which case you ought to know how you configured it—or some derived product like Aquamacs—in which case we'd need to know which one you're using before anyone can answer.

Comment: I'm from the future. Woooooooo ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general I would do `M-x describe-function RET python-mode`--by default bound to <kbd>C-h f</kbd>-- and the first line in the info window is: ``` python-mode is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ``python.el' ```.

And that `python.el` is clickable, for me, and takes me to the file that it was defined in, at which point `M-x pwd` works.